# How to debug kernel panics on Jammy

Tags: 22.04, crash

Online guides from google on using kdump and the crash utility point to using kernel debug symbols with the crash utility.  I'm not able to find the debug symbols package for Jammy.

How can I find the steps for debugging kernel panics on Jammy?

Version: 22.04.3 LTS Jammy Jellyfish
Kernel: 6.5.0-25-generic